# Solving Linear System Word Problem

Tags: systems-of-equations, word-problem

For example, if a person wants to earn 250 dollars doing yardwork, and can earn 8 dollars/per hour weeding flower beds and $10/per hour mowing lawn,and wants to work a total of 200 hours, how can you format this to find out how many hours each job must be done? Using the the ax+by=c format.

Comment: Is there more information, such as the amount of time the person has?

Comment: Perhaps you could state the full problem along with your suggestion to form one equation from it?

Comment: Take your one equation and multiply both sides by the same number, different from zero to get the second equation.  I suspect it's not what you've been asked, but it certainly works.

Comment: You were right, I was missing a piece of information!

Comment: @Kate Are you sure you have put the information correctly? You simply can't work for a negative amount of hours.

Comment: @Kate (See my answer for details.)

Comment: The number of hours worked has to be between 25 (all lawn-mowing) and 31.25 (all weeding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let:

- $x$ be the amount of hours weeding flower beds
- $y$ be the amount of hours mowing lawn.

So, the equation system is
$$\left\{\begin{array}08x+10y=250\\
x+y=200\end{array}\right.$$

### Steps to solve

Multiplying the second equation by $8$ yields
$$\left\{\begin{array}08x+10y=250\\
8x+8y=1600\end{array}\right.$$
Subtracting the second equation from the first yields
$$2y=-1350\\
y=-675$$
Substituting that into $x+y=200$ yields
$$x+(-675)=200\\
x=200+675\\
x=875$$
Therefore, $x=875$ and $y=-675$.